# How to make some websites appear higher on Google?

Tags: google-search

I often google for programming related stuff, and whenever there's an article on a few sites I enjoy reading such as the `developer.mozilla.org`, I would like to have them at the top of the search results. Is there a way to do that? I have been pressing the favorite icon, but it is tied to the particular page only.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this, doing it more complex, maybe adding a shortcut for not typing it everytime, etc, would be the solution :

whatever the terms site:developer.mozilla.org || site:anotherprogrammingsite.com || site:otherone.com ...

using "" for 'whatever the terms'  (random sentence, could be programming in java, or python parser, etc)  for full sentence search or not, like always.